# Show that the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ by Binomial Theorem is convergent when $x<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> *To show that the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ by Binomial Theorem is convergent when $x<1$*

Let $u_r, u_{r+1}$ represent the $r^{th}$ and $(r + 1)^{th}$ terms of the expansion; then

$$\frac{u_{r+1}}{u_r}=\frac{n-r+1}{r}x$$

When $r>n+1$, this ratio is negative; that is, from this 
point the terms are alternately positive and negative when $x$ 
is positive, and always of the same sign when $x$ is negative.

Now when $r$ is infinite, $Lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{u_{r+1}}{u_r} = x$ numerically ; therefore 
since $x < 1$ the series is convergent if all the terms are of the 
same sign ; and therefore a fortiori it is convergent when some of 
the terms are positive and some negative. $\blacklozenge$

---

Question 1: The Binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ has $(n+1)$ terms, then how can $r>n+1$?

Question 2: from this 
point the terms are alternately positive and negative when $x$ 
is positive, and always of the same sign when $x$ is negative, (How ?)

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Proof,  http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/binomialTheorem.htm#Convergence

Comment: Can't you just say that it is power series and find it's radius of convergence?